# PHP rename File everyday

Tags: php, rename, file-rename

im reciving a csv everyday on my server.
Im trying to delete the old file and rename the new file.

```
unlink("old.csv");
```

the new csv has everyday a new filename. On 7th March the file is called 
`new20200307.csv` on the 8th March 
`new20200308.csv` and so on

How to I rename the newfile into `old.csv`? With that code its renaming my old files into `new20200308new.csv`

```
<?php
$directory = '/cronjob/smart/';
foreach (glob($directory."*.csv") as $filename) {
    $file = realpath($filename);
    rename($file, str_replace(".csv","new.csv",$file));
}
?>
```

Comment: `rename($file, 'old.csv');`?

Comment: If you want the filename to be "old.csv", why aren't you using that in the call to `rename()` like `rename($file, $directory."old.csv");`?

Comment: What's the exact problem with renaming here? Maybe you want to check whether the filename generated by `str_replace` is the name you expect?

Comment: Sorry for the missunderstanding - 
everyday a new csv gets pushed. I want to delete the csv from yesterday, and rename the file from today in something like old.csv.

Comment: "_something like_ old.csv" or _exactly_ "old.csv"?  You need to be precise here.  Also, I don't think any of us misunderstood what you've _said_, although it still may not be what you actually _mean_.  If you are always saving the new file as "old.csv", then that's always going to be the name of the file that you will be deleting, and therefore no need to search the entire directory.

Comment: If you're running this in cron job, wouldn't the current file name be `'new' . date('Ymd') . '.csv'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand fully the question, with something like that:

```
rename($file, 'old.csv');
```

if $file is new20200308.csv will become old.csv

Comment: But the filename changes everyday, so i need to rename every csv. not only new20200308.csv, because on the next it is 20200309.csv

Comment: But with `glob` you get the file you want to edit. Does this script run daily as well?